# Hiding Components in order to keep their state in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with children. I would like these to be shown or not depending on the press of a button. I can do this by creating a state variable childrenVisible, and then rendering or not depending on it.

But I have noticed that if I have state on a child Component it will get reset when toggling childrenVisible. I think this is because components gets destroyed when not rendered on a re-render.

I would like to keep the elements around, so I can keep their state, but just hide them depending on childrenVisible. Is this possible in React?

Comment: use `display: none` ?

Comment: Seems you are conditionally rendering specific children components. Try instead passing a "isVisible" prop to each child and have the child conditionally render `null` when you want it to be hidden.

Comment: @azium Good idea. If you write it in an answer I can accept. I'm still interested in if there are React specific ways. Maybe something where you could keep the state of your elements, without even adding them to the DOM.

Comment: @drew Thanks, that's even better.

Comment: Yes, both will work - `display: none` or `return null`. I'd prefer returning null. You can find a Codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-render-react-g3jy2).

Comment: I guess you can also consider holding the content of the your child state into a parent state and passing it down through a prop